# How to remove gap between product categories in WooCommerce Shop?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I started recently to customize one site, but have one issue that don't know how to fix.

in Shop page on my [URL](http://www.thenichehairstudio.com.au/shop/)

when try to open from smartphone there are too big gap between top, and between product categories I see this:

[image: See image]

I tried myself to remove that gap using this CSS:

```
  .woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products 
li.product {
            min-height: 420px !important;
        }
```

But seems that also affect Product Archives page, makes bad looking. How to add css for mobile only to fix that? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using the following style :

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    margin-bottom: -100px;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
min-height: 490px !important;
margin-bottom: 0px;
```

}

You should remove **min-height** and **margin-bottom** to fix the height issues within the products. And above the product section you have padding with **header-content** and **wrapper-content**, please change according to your screen size.

Hope that work.

Comment: That dont change nothing.. Removed that CSS, but when check from smartphone, nothing changes.

Comment: I checked and that works for me.. please check after clearing the cache...

Comment: I get this : http://i.imgur.com/YrNpGZv.png?1  after commenting that lines CSS you listed before, also cleared cache.

Comment: You forget to remove margin-bottom:-100px; or add margin-bottom:0px !important;

Comment: Now is fine, except top gap in shop page. How to resolve that also ?

Comment: I fixed myself adding this:

`@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    #wrapper .header-content {
    padding: 0px 5%;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I have two answers of the question you can do whatever you like to do, its up to you.

1. Remove the min-height 490px

.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {

```
min-height: 490px !important;

margin-bottom: 0px;
```

}

and

.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {

```
margin-bottom: -170px!important;
```

}

this from css

and second please add the css to your page where you wrote the css like here http://prntscr.com/faq33h as you wrote css.

@media (max-width: 480px) {

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {

    min-height: 425px !important;

    margin-bottom: 0px;

}
```

}

@media (max-width: 375px){

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {

    min-height: 400px !important;

    margin-bottom: 0px;

}
```

}
@media (max-width: 375px){

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {

    min-height: 365px !important;

    margin-bottom: 0px;

}
```

}

if you have any question please let me know.

Comment: Adding your code makes this:

1. http://i.imgur.com/eBLmkFC.png?1  - shop page
2. product archive page - http://i.imgur.com/tDITrFN.png?1

Comment: just make the condition 
<?php is_page('shop'){ ?>
<style>my css </style>
<?php } ?>
you need to add them on the page where you wrote the css for
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {

min-height: 490px !important;

margin-bottom: 0px;
}

or just remove the min height and margin-bottom and check in incognito window of chrome and press ctrl+f5

Comment: I added but nothing changed.. entire site makes mess after adding your code. Check currently how looks with your code.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add if condition just try it it will definitely work for you.
<?php if(is_page('shop')){ ?>
<style>My style</style>
<?php } ?>